# Windows service to change window focus

Tags: windows-services, z-order

I am trying to use a Windows Service to change between the window focus between 2 different applications (one I am currently developing, and google chrome).

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Not possible, or at least not directly.  Window focus can only be affected by an application running in the interactive session; services always run in a non-interactive session.  Why a service?

Comment: To be fair, I expected windows services to enable it since they handle some background tasks. I guess that clears it then.

Comment: Services are most suitable for tasks that must run even when nobody is logged on, or that require administrator privilege.  In this case, a conventional background process, running as the user, would probably be more appropriate.